# PostgreSQL Enum type. Pros and cons

Tags: postgresql, enum

PostgreSQL has an [Enum data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html). What are the pros and cons of using Enums?
I found the [advantages for MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) but don't know which apply for PostgreSQL and to what extend:

> Readable queries and output.

Comment: "An `enum` value occupies four bytes on disk." I'm guessing they have the same efficiency as `integer`

Comment: Have you checked [ENUM — Enumerated Types](https://medium.com/swlh/postgresql-3-ways-to-replace-enum-305861e089bc#4d81) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Advantages for enum types:

- The values in the tables can be understood without consulting a lookup table. (That is pretty irrelevant, since you don't use a database interactively as a rule. If you do, consider using a spreadsheet instead.)
- No need for an extra lookup table that you have to join with. (This is also not very relevant, since those joins are cheap.)
- Potentially better query estimates for

  ```
  ... FROM tab WHERE tab.e = 'somevalue'
  ```

  as compared to

  ```
  ... FROM tab JOIN look USING (look_id) WHERE look.v = 'somevalue'
  ```
- Enums have a well-defined sort order if you need that. (But you can also define a column that determines the sorting order to a lookup table.)

Disadvantages:

- You cannot remove an enum value, so don't use enums for anything where a value might go away.
- I don't think enums are in the SQL standard, so they make porting to other databases harder.

Comment: Could you explain `cannot remove an enum value`?

Comment: Also, would it be a problem to remove/add an enum value from the available ones, every 2 months?

Comment: There is no `ALTER TYPE ... DROP VALUE ...`.